# Nudity detection in python

Tags: python, performance, classification, image-classification

I'm classifying a dataset of **10.000 images** into nudes/not nudes in google colab(python)

I'm using the NudeClassifier from nudenet, which mainly works like this.

```
from nudenet import NudeClassifier

# initialize classifier (downloads the checkpoint file automatically the first time)
classifier = NudeClassifier()

# A. Classify single image
print(classifier.classify('./image1.jpg'))

# This would print something like:
# {
#   './image1.jpg': {
#      'safe': 0.00015856953, 
#      'unsafe': 0.99984145
#   }
# }

# B. Classify multiple images
# Returns {'path_to_image_1': {'safe': PROBABILITY, 'unsafe': PROBABILITY}}
# Classify multiple images (batch prediction)
# batch_size is optional; defaults to 4
print(
    classifier.classify(
        ['./image1.jpg', './image2.jpg', './image3.jpg', './image4.jpg'],
        batch_size=4
    )
)
```

The problem is that, using a loop and classifying each image individually takes a lot of time (1s aprox. for image)

Using this last option, would a bigger bacth_size make the classification problem run faster?

in that case, which would be the ideal batch_size for this problem?

thank you very much

Comment: Why not just try varying the batch-size to see what happens? You should probably watch the memory usage whilst doing that. If a larger size doesn't greastly improve the performance, try [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of inference, the batch size just defines how many images will be loaded into the memory to be processed at once. So the larger the batch size, the faster the inference will be.

Of course the limit is the size of your memory, so you can estimate how far you can raise it.

If it is still too slow, consider inference on GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the batch size defenitely improves the inference time on multiple images. The batch size will vary depending upon the GPU memory available. Try to set a batch size that completely utilises the available GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but you may want to try [OpenNSFW 2](https://github.com/bhky/opennsfw2), which has a better support for inference on image batches. You could even generate [Grad-CAM](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) for each image (see [usage](https://github.com/bhky/opennsfw2#predict_images)) to have a better clue of the model decision. Under the hood it is a TensorFlow/Keras model.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33509760)